# Obtaining the KG equation from Action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, variational-calculus, klein-gordon-equation, modified-gravity

After solving the field equation for

$$S = \int \sqrt{-g}dx^4[f(\phi)R + h(\phi)g^{\mu 
\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\phi\nabla_{\nu}\phi - V(\phi)]$$

I have obtained

$$2h\square \phi + \frac{\partial h}{\partial \phi}\nabla^{\mu}\phi\nabla_{\mu}\phi - R\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} = 0~~(*)$$

It seems that the action for the inflation is

$$S = \int \sqrt{-g}dx^4[\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}\nabla_{\mu}\phi\nabla_{\nu}\phi - V(\phi)]$$

Thus for $f=0$ and $h=1/2$ $(*)$ gives,

$$\square \phi +\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}=0$$

so I am getting

$$\ddot{\phi} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}=0$$ from here but the inflation field equation is

$$\ddot{\phi} + 3H\dot{\phi} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} = 0$$

So is there terms missing in $(*)$, or am I am doing something wrong..?

Or can we obtain KG equation from the given $(*)$..maybe there should be something at the right side of the $(*)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\square \phi = V'(\phi)$ does not imply $\ddot{\phi} = V'(\phi)$ as you have implied. The covariant derivative term $\square \phi$ contains the metric tensor, and consequent connection terms, so that is where the Hubble factor $H(t)$ comes from.

Another hint, consider that $$\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu}\phi = \partial_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu} \phi + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu \nu} \nabla^{\nu} \phi$$

Comment: Oh yes, I get it now..Thanks a lot. I don't know why I have not seen that...

Comment: See my additional comment

Comment: It would be better if you have used other symbol then $\mu$ in the Chris. Symbol. (right?)

Comment: No, these are summed

Comment: ok okay. my mistake again..

Comment: No worries. Sean Carroll's textbook on GR (freely available online) has a lot of these calculations, it could be useful for this sort of thing

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. I got really tired for trying to calculate the whole thing.